How to show that, the weak topology is the coarsest topology such that all $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ are continuous?
Let E be a normed space, $E':=\{f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}| f \text{ is continuous and linear}\}$. Define $p_f(x):=|f(x)| where f \in E'$ and $x \in E$. Consider the family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}=\{p_f |f \in E'\}$.
The topology induced by $\mathcal{P}$ is called the weak topology.
The weak topology is the coarsest topology such that every $f \in E'$ is continuous.
I would like to show the topology induced by $\mathcal{P}$ is the "coarsest topology such that every $f \in E'$ is continuous".
I will call the topology induced by $\mathcal{P}$ $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$.
I have thought about two ways to approach this:
Approach 1:
My first idea was to just go by the definition of coarsest topology, i.e.
Suppose $\tau$ is a topolgy such that  every $f \in E'$ is continuous.
I need to show that $\tau_{\mathcal{P}} \subseteq \tau$.
Approach 2:
The idea hear is to use topology to "generate" the coarsest topology and then show that it is euqal to $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$.
Let $X$ be a set and let Pow denote the power set.
I know that if $\mathcal{S}\subseteq Pow(X)$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for the coarsest topology $\tau$ on $X$ such all Elements of $\mathcal{S}$ are open.
I thought about defining $\mathcal{S}:=\{f^{-1}(U)| f \in E' \text{ and } U \text{ open in } \mathbb{K}\}$.
By defining $\mathcal{B}:=\{\cap_{S \in \mathcal{F}} |\mathcal{F} \subseteq S, \mathcal{F} \text{is finite}\}$ I can obtain a basis for the topology. If I now let $\tau:=\{\cup_{B \in \mathcal{C}} B|\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{B} \}$ I obtain the coarsest topology such that each $f \in E'$ is continuous, i.e. $\tau \subseteq \tau_{\mathcal{P}}$. The only thing left to show is: $\tau_{\mathcal{P}} \subseteq \tau$.
So, let $U \in \tau_{\mathcal{P}}$. Being open w.r.t $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$ means that for every $x_0 \in U$ there exist $p_1,...,p_n$ and $r_1,...,r_n$ such that $\cap_{i=1}^n B_{p_i}(x_0,r_i) \subseteq U$, where $B_{p}(x_0,r):=\{x \in E |p(x-x_0)<r\}$.
For $U$ to be open w.r.t $\tau$ means that there exist $f_1,...,f_n$ and $U_1,..., U_n$ open in $\mathbb{K}$ such that $\cap_{i=1}^n f^{-1}_i(U_i) \subseteq U$.
But I do not know how to argue that final step. Help or solution would be very appreciated.

If a net $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ wrt to $τ$ then since each $f \in E'$ is $τ$-continuous, you get that $f(x_i) \to f(x)$ for every such $f$, i.e. $ x_i \to x$ in the weak topology $τ_\mathcal P$. This shows that the identinty $Id : (E,τ) \to (E,τ_\mathcal P)$ is continuous, i.e. $τ_\mathcal P \subset τ$.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thank you very much!
